# On successful password reset user stays on success status page

Tags: fusionauth

On successfull reset of the password from the forgot password email link, user stays at the success status screen.

On successfull password reset, I would like to redirect the user to the fusion auth login page or to my application. One way I am thinking is to write some custom javascript to automatically redirect the user but the challenge is we have 3 applications under a tenant and theme templates are specific to the tenant, how would be I able to differentiate the redirect url?

Comment: If the user initiates the password change from a FusionAuth themed page, this should be handled automatically.  If you have alternate flows where you generate the link yourself or initiate the reset from an API or the admin UI - you'll have to handle the redirect in JavaScript.

Comment: Hi @robotdan, can you please tell me if there is a way to detect for which application this reset password is triggered? So, I can detect application on success page and redirect the user via script.